# Using magnifier.js to generate a magnifying glass on my image

Tags: javascript, css, image

I've been trying to create a magnifying glass for my images so I went online and found this: http://mark-rolich.github.io/Magnifier.js/

I'm looking to use the one with mode set to 'inside' and I would like it to work the way it does in his demo. I removed commented out the wrapper section since I'm using mode: 'inside'

I'm not really sure what to make of magnifier.css but I made my own Magnifier.js and Event.js links and they seem to be working.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magnifier.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.enviroptics.com/Matt/js/Event.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.enviroptics.com/Matt/js/Magnifier.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var evt = new Event(),
    m = new Magnifier(evt);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
 <a class="magnifier-thumb-wrapper" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Starry_Night_Over_the_Rhone.jpg">
    <img id="thumb" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/Starry_Night_Over_the_Rhone.jpg/200px-Starry_Night_Over_the_Rhone.jpg">
 </a>
<!--    <div class="magnifier-preview" id="preview" style="width: 200px; height: 133px">Starry Night Over The Rhone<br>by Vincent van Gogh</div>-->
</div>

<script>
m.attach({
    thumb: '#thumb',
    large: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/Starry_Night_Over_the_Rhone.jpg/1200px-Starry_Night_Over_the_Rhone.jpg',
    mode: 'inside',
zoom: 3,
zoomable: true
});
</script>
</body>
```

Heres a link to the w3schools i've been working in http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=F0EBCN2SLPOI

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you did with the JS files, you can add your own CSS as well.

I added the url for the css on http://mark-rolich.github.io/Magnifier.js/, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mark-rolich.github.io/Magnifier.js/magnifier.css">
```

And it seems to be working. Here is a link to the page on w3schools (Just added the url to your code):
http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=F0F991Z62KJ7